# VS2010 C++ unmanaged compiling as managed - CLR.dll crash on exit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, clr, memory-access

I am working on an unmanaged C++ project in VS2010.  The project was originally created as a windows console application (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE, with preprocessor definition _CONSOLE, using _tmain() as the entry point).  I have changed it to a window application in order to have more functionality for the interface (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS, with preprocessor definition _WINDOWS, using _tWinMain() as the entry point).

Starts and runs perfectly, but when I exit the application, just as the window disappears, I get a dialog saying executable has stopped working.  Clicked Debug, selected VS2010 that is already open with the project, and then got another dialog saying executable has stopped working.  When I click Debug on that one, I get another dialog saying "A debugger is attched to  but not configured to debug this unhandled exception.  An unhandled exception is being thrown from .NET Framework v4.0 code".

**NOTE:** This crash only occurs when the application is run as release by double-clicking the app icon.  When I'm running in the VS2010 IDE it exits gracefully.

I thought that strange, since my project is defined as Win32 using standard windows libraries.  So I looked at the system's error log and found that the error for my executable reads as follows:

Faulting application name: , version: 1.0.0.1, timestamp 0x5638a404
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.34014, time stamp: 0x52e0b784
Exception code: 0xc0000005

Looked into this and found that the CLR.dll is .NET managed.  I am not sure why this is being used by my application now.  Looked through my project properties and don't see any reference to it being needed, so I assume that when I changed to SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS, or to preprocessor _WINDOWS, or both, it must have been included as a requirement.

I then looked up the text "" and found the following link (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2640103) that has the title **FIX: Faulting module name: clr.dll error message when you run a Microsoft .NET Framework 4-based application**.  This seems to point to my application now being built as a .NET application, which is not the intent.

Can anyone tell me why I'm accessing the CLR.dll when running my executable? And why my application is being built as .NET 4 when it wasn't doing so before? At this point I have no idea how to find out why it's throwing an access error, but I assume it's because the application isn't coded to handle .NET 4.

Comment: This is all pretty vague and requires wild guessing.  Getting clr.dll injected into a native program is certainly not impossible.  A poorly implemented shell extension can do it.  You'll need to keep in eye on the Debug > Windows > Modules window and the Output window that displays debugger notifications when a DLL gets loaded into your process.  If my blind guess is accurate then you might see it getting loaded when you use one of the shell dialogs.

Comment: Just edited to add this, but this crash only occurs when the application is run as release by double-clicking the app icon.  When I'm running in the VS2010 IDE it exits gracefully.  I would love if it would crash when in the IDE.  It might make it easier to see what was happening at the time.  I did look in the Modules window for the old and new projects and the old does not have CLR.dll in the list, while the new one does.

Comment: Ok, found the answer.  Should have realized there was a dll being loaded that was compiled with .NET.  Works on my Win7 32 bit without a crash, since the clr.dll is not framework version 4, but on my Win8 64 bit, seems that the clr.dll is version 4, which doesn't match with the project definition.  Problem solved.  Still need to figure out how to get this not to crash on my Win8.